# How to add nar files to Intelij IDEA project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am working on project, which requires nar files to build and compile JAVA project. 
How to add this files to Intelij IDEA IDE?

I know steps for .jar and library files but when I tried same approach to add .nar files, that folder shows as empty folder under Intelij.

https://medium.com/hashmapinc/nifi-nar-files-explained-14113f7796fd
reference of NAR files.

Eclipse is easily identifying these files, but I prefer coding with Intelij IDEA

Clearly below steps are not working;
Click File from the toolbar
Project Structure (CTRL + SHIFT + ALT + S on Windows/Linux, ⌘ + ; on Mac OS X)
Select Modules at the left panel
Dependencies tab
'+' → JARs or directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I'm seeing on the page you linked to, you will need to unpack the file (see the "How to Unpack a NAR on the Command Line" section on that page) and then added the extracted "bundled dependencies" directory as a library in IDEA. The issue is that the `*.nar` file does not directly contain the classes to add as dependencies. It wraps JAR files. And you need to add the JAR files as dependencies.